# WPF Datagridview Equivalencies

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid, grid

I'm pretty new to WPF (I've worked with Windows Forms before) and I used DataGridView elements many times, but now I've switched to DataGrid in WPF and boy I'm in trouble...

What I want to do is to "create" the DataGrid with the dimensions entered in a textBox called sizeBox when I click on the button called size. Inside the event in the code I have the following lines:

```
try
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            int size;
            int i = 0;
            size = Convert.ToInt32(this.sizeBox.Text);
            int sizegridh = Grid.Size.Height;
            int sizegridw = Grid.Size.Width;
            int sizecellh = sizegridh / size;
            int sizecellw = sizegridw / size;
            for (i = 1; i <= size; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add();
                dt.Rows.Add();
                Grid.DataSource = dt;

            }
            for (i = 1; i <= size; i++)
            {
                Grid.Rows[i - 1].Height = sizecellh;
                Grid.Columns[i - 1].Width = sizecellw;

            }
        }
```

What this code should do is, for example, if we enter the number 5, create a 5x5 Grid on the existing DataView which is empty until we enter the value.

The problems I have are:

- Grid.Size.Height is not a valid command, and I can't find the equivalency in WPF's DataGrid, same with the Width
- Grid.DataSource = dt; does not work
- Grid.Rows[i] or Columns is not the right way to select a certain value, which is the equivalent one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> `Grid.Size.Height` is not a valid command, and I can't find the
>   equivalency in WPF's `DataGrid`, same with the `Width`

There are [`Width`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Height`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties.
*But*, before setting them, note, that WPF is *layout*-based, while WinForms
is *coordinate*-based. In short, there are rather rare cases, when you want to set size explicitly. Before you will continue, I strongly recommend you to read about [layout controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans).

> `Grid.DataSource = dt;` does not work

Because there is [`ItemsSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx).

> `Grid.Rows[i]` or `Columns` is not the right way to select a certain value, which is the equivalent one?

WPF is all about [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Do not try to work with WPF controls like in WinForms.

Comment: What I would like to do is to let the user introduce a number, let's say 5, and create an empty (and visible) 5x5 "matrix". Each "cell" will have a temperature and another parameter associated to the coordinate that it represents on the matrix. How can I create this "matrix" and let's say, get the text or whatever is written in the 2nd row 3rd column cell for example? Thanks!!